# Open url in new tab with middle click via JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I try to write some code in order to open a url in new tab when I press middle click. I tried some things that I saw from previous questions but I didn't succeed to solve my problem. my code is this :

```
if(event.mousedown == 0) {
            window.open($link.text(), "", "width:" + width + ",height:" + height);      }
            else if (event.button == 1) {
                 window.open($link.text(), '_blank')    }
        }
```

Comment: This is the default behaviour in most browsers. Why do you need to redefine it?

Comment: Because in my website they don’t open with middle click for some reason

Comment: Then analyse that reason and fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
const link = document.querySelector('a');

link.addEventListener('mousedown', (event) => {  
  if(event.button === 0) {
      window.open(link.href, '_self')
  } else if (event.button === 1) {
      window.open(link.href, '_blank')
  }
})
```

```html
<a href="https://google.com">Link</a>
```